# What is the message?

Tags: cipher

I  got a message for you if you can read it:

hrGBjXPkYF41h7m14s18m11s9m31s12m33s18m56s59m24s

The message is in english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message is:

> I see too little challenge congratulation.

As for how to resolve it:

> hrGBjXPkYF4 is the ID for a Youtube video. Then the message is divided in video times where you have to pick up each of the words.

Comment: That was quick the message proved true